# Can I/O pins on a PLD (e.g. ATF16V8B) be configured to act as an open-drain output that is usable in a wired-OR circuit?

Tags: programmable-logic, open-drain

I designed a peripheral card for an 8-bit home computer which uses an ATF16V8B for address decoding and glue logic.

I want this card to be able to generate interrupt requests by driving the system's /IRQ line low.

Normally, this signal is weakly pulled up to VCC through a 10K resistor, enabling multiple devices to share the signal line in a typical wired-OR configuration.

Of course, I ordered PCB's before considering the implications of this, and I've simply connected the /IRQ signal to an I/O pin on the PLD, as pictured. I already have a UART in my system which shares the /IRQ, so I have to play nice.

Can this design be made to work as intended, without having to bodge the board, by just configuring the PLD properly?  I'm using the old WINCUPL utility, and haven't been able to find an example of configuring an I/O pin as open drain.

If a HW change is needed, would the simplest way be to interpose a transistor/resistor between the I/O pin and the /IRQ signal, or is there something simpler? The actual situation which I want to cause the /IRQ to drive low is whenever the SRX (push-pull) signal goes high. This signal happens to be connected to input pin 9, which can also be configured to act as an /OE.

[image: Schematic of a peripheral card]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though there are some limitations. It might be helpful to share the CUPL source code so we can understand how your design works.

If any outputs are registered then all registered outputs use pin 11 (I9/OE) as their common output enable. Conveniently you have SRX connected to pin 11 which could work, but that means SRX going high will tristate any other registered pins: potentially STX and ORX.

If the IRQ output isn't registered you can specify an output enable with the ".oe" suffix and simulate an open drain output that can only go low and never high as follows:

```
irq = 'b'0; // drive IRQ low when output is enabled
irq.oe = srx; // only turn on output enable when SRX goes high
```

If neither of those options work due to design constraints, the simplest bodge is to put a diode between the IRQ pin and the rest of the IRQ trace, with the cathode towards the ATF16V8. This allows the IRQ pin to sink current when the PLD drives it low through the diode, but does not conduct when the IRQ pin is high. This also simulates an open drain output.

Comment: That's good news! I hadn't shared the CUPL code because it hasn't been written yet, but I intended to configure the part in simple mode rather than registered mode.  I'm going to try the .oe option right away. Thank you for addressing the contingencies too. I hadn't thought of the diode bodge-- that strikes me as a clever idea. I would upvote the answer but I apparently don't have enough rep yet or something.